# Fazer função aguardar variável ser gerada

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, async

tenho o seguinte codigo:

```
XmlParaApi = xml;
```

que passa uma variável em string (xml) para uma variavel global em string (XmlParaApi). Até ai tudo este código se encontra em uma Api, a gora o meu problema é com o código abaixo:

```
 string XmlApi = XmlApi.XmlParaApi;
```

O problema ocorre pois eu faço duas funções ocorrerem simultaneamente, só que preciso que o segundo código espere a variável (XmlParaApi) estar pronta para ser utilizada, andei vendo que tem uma forma de fazer pelo "wait", mas não tenho conseguido fazer, alguém pode ajudar?

Answer (score 0):

onde você deve esperar, você pode usar um while...

ex:

```
    While (String.IsNullOrEmpty(XmlApi))
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
    }
```

obs. Estou considerando que a variável será preenchida em outra thread, e que sempre será preenchida. Caso contrário, coloque algum gatilho para sair do while por exemplo, depois de 100 tentativas, para que a aplicação não fique travada nesse comando.